# Primeng loading icon is not updating

Tags: lazy-loading, angular5, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am using primeng turbo table with lazy loading and enabled loading to attribute it's not getting updated even got updated

```
<p-table #dt [loading]="loader" [columns]="cols" [value]="datasource.merchants" [rows]="perPage" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="5"
      [lazy]="true" [totalRecords]="datasource.totalCount" (onLazyLoad)="loadLazyData($event)" [exportFilename]="'merchant-list'">
.....
```

Script

```
loadLazyData(event: LazyLoadEvent) {    
    if (event.first !== this.searchParams.offset || event.rows !== this.searchParams.limit) {
      this.loader = true;
      this.searchParams.offset = event.first;
      this.searchParams.limit = event.rows;
     this.apiService.getResponse(this.smartSearchParams.query, event.first, event.rows)
          .subscribe((result) => {
            this.datasource = result;
            let newArray = result.merchants.slice();
            this.dataTable.value = newArray;
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.loader = false;
              this.dataTable.loading = this.loader;
            });
          }, (err: any) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.loader = false;
              this.dataTable.loading = this.loader;
            });
          });

      }
```

can someone help me with this issue

Comment: does this.loader = true ever get executed? of you remove the if statement does it work? if so the problem with related to your if statement conditions.

Comment: @floor this.loader =true is got executed, value got updated but still loader is not stoping

Comment: do you have errors in the console? does your endpoint return data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with `changeDetection` for the component.

I have removed the `changeDetection:ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` from my component its started working